# SharePoint provider hosted apps issue

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint povider hosted apps. i configureed in my local system using this link "http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-provider-hosted-app.html" but while i click on f5 i am getting this issu
"An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Can you please Help me how to resolve this. "brahmanaidu.medathi@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

If you run into **401 unauthorized error** when running a high-trust app / add-in.

Try the steps below:
Use the PowerShell cmdlet to get the List of all TrustedSecurityTokenIssuer in your Farm
        Get-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer | select Name,RegisteredIssuerName | fl

This shows the Name, Registered Issuer Name for all registered security token issuers.  I had five of them.
The first one 00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 is for Workflows.
Observe rest of the list, the correct token issuer should be of the format issuerID@Realm if you have a registration in there that’s missing the issuerID or Realm portion of the RegisteredIssuerName, you can see the 401 error. 
For us it is 29b0ebdd-791b-41c3-b1f7-a4152a1b7a8d@8165b002-8510-4d2d-b0f7-67b0a716a3f6. The portion before ‘@’ is our ‘issuerID’ and after is the ‘Realm’ (ref to the above screenshot).
The realm should be the same for any issuers that you registered manually, and it should be the same as your farm ID (use the below cmdlet to find that):
        Get-SPFarm | select Id

And you can verify the Realm using the below cmdlet

```
    $spurl ="http://sp/sites/DevCenter" 
    $spsite = Get-SPSite $spurl 
    $realm = Get-SPAuthenticationRealm -ServiceContext $spsite 
    Write $realm
```

If you see a token issuers that is not in correct format, that’s the killer and you must remove that (but don’t dare to remove the one for the workflows Smile). You can use the below PS to remove any SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer. Make sure to supply correct RegisteredIssuerName found above.

```
    Get-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer | ?{$_.RegisteredIssuerName -eq "29b0ebdd-791b-41c3-b1f7-a4152a1b7a8d@8165b002-8510-4d2d-b0f7-67b0a716a3f6"} | Remove-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer
```

You should also double-check that you are using the correct public key portion (the .CER file) for the private key (the .PFX file) that is on your app’s IIS server.  It is always worth verifying this step again. 
Then make sure that the issuerID that’s in the RegisteredIssuerName (before the “@” symbol) matches the value that you have in web.config. Open the web.config file of your App’s web project.

```
    <appSettings>
<add key="ClientId" value="xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="ClientSigningCertificatePath" value="C:\Certificate\xxxxx.pfx" />
<add key="ClientSigningCertificatePassword" value="xxxxxx" />
<!--<add key="IssuerId" value="dd278404-6abc-4eb2-a33a-6bc1aa67a136" /> Old Incorrect ID-->
<add key="IssuerId" value="d250d0bc-d44e-4d8b-9e36-567817943628" />
    </appSettings>
```

Also navigate to the ‘Site App Permissions’ page and you will see all the App Identifier listed. Notice that your App Identifier is of the structure ClientID@Realm. Verify the clientId in the web.config (above step).;
image

Next, use
        Get-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer

and look at the certificate thumbprint for your issuer and compare it with the thumbprint of the certificate you used in PowerShell.